# Apply rotation to HEALPix map in healpy

Tags: python, rotator, healpy

I have a HEALPix map that I have read in using healpy, however it is in galactic coordinates and I need it in celestial/equatorial coordinates. Does anybody know of a simple way to convert the map?

I have tried using `healpy.Rotator` to convert from (l,b) to (phi,theta) and then using `healpy.ang2pix` to reorder the pixels, but the map still looks strange.

It would be great if there was a function similar to `Rotator` that you could call like: `map = AnotherRotator(map,coord=['G','C'])`. Anybody know of any such function??

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert and save healpy map to different coordinate system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443498/how-to-convert-and-save-healpy-map-to-different-coordinate-system)

Comment: see a solution in [this other Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66468476/rotating-a-healpyor-healpix-map-to-an-arbitrary-direction/66593198#66593198)

Answer (score 3):

I realise that this was asked ages ago, but I was having the same problem myself this week and found your post. I've found a couple of potential solutions, so I'll share incase someone else comes upon this and finds it useful.

**Solution 1**: This sort of depends on the format your data is coming in. Mine came in a (theta, phi) grid.

```
import numpy as np
import healpy as H
map = <your original map>
nside = <your map resolution, mine=256>
npix = H.nside2npix(nside)
pix = N.arange(npix)
t,p = H.pix2ang(nside,pix) #theta, phi

r = H.Rotator(deg=True, rot=[<THETA ROTATION>, <PHI ROTATION>])

map_rot = np.zeros(npix)

for i in pix:
    trot, prot = r(t[i],p[i])
    tpix = int(trot*180./np.pi) #my data came in a theta, phi grid -- this finds its location there
    ppix = int(prot*180./np.pi)
    map_rot[i] = map[ppix,tpix] #this being the rright way round may need double-checking
```

**Solution 2**: Haven't quite finished testing this, but just came across it AFTER doing the annoying work above...

```
map_rot = H.mollview(map,deg=True,rot=[<THETA>,<PHI>], return_projected_map=True)
```

which gives a 2D numpy array. I'm interested to know how to convert this back into a healpix map...

Answer (score 3):

I found another potential solution, after searching off and on for a few months. I haven't tested it very much yet, so please be careful!

Saul's **Solution 2**, above, is the key (great suggestion!)

Basically, you combine the functionality of `healpy.mollview` (`gnomview`, `cartview`, and `orthview` work as well) with that of the `reproject_to_healpix` function in the `reproject` package (http://reproject.readthedocs.org/en/stable/).

The resulting map is suitable for my angular scales, but I can't say how accurate the transformation is compared to other methods.

**-----Basic Outline----------**

**Step 1:** Read-in the map and make the rectangular array via `cartview`. As Saul indicated above, this is also one way to do the rotation. If you're just doing a standard rotation/coordinate transformation, then all you need is the `coord` keyword. From Celestial to Galactic coordinates, set `coord = ['C','G']`

```
map_Gal = hp.cartview(map_Cel, coord=['C','G'], return_projected_map=True, xsize=desired_xsize, norm='hist',nest=False)
```

**Step 2:** Write a template all-sky FITS header (as in the example below). I wrote mine to have the same *average* pixel-scale as my desired HEALPix map.

**Step 3:** Use `reproject.transform_to_healpix`

`reproject` includes a function for mapping a "normal" array (or FITS file) into the HEALPix projection. Combine that with the ability to return the array created by healpy.mollview/cartview/orthview/gnomview, and you can rotate a HEALPix map of one coordinate system (Celestial) into another coordinate system (Galactic).

```
map_Gal_HP, footprint_Gal_HP = rp.reproject_to_healpix((map_Gal, target_header), coord_system_out= 'GALACTIC', nside=nside, nested=False)
```

It comes down, essentially, to those two commands. However **you'll have to make a template header**, giving the pixel scale and size corresponding to the intermediary all-sky map you want to make.

**-----Full Working Example (iPython notebook format + FITS sample data)------**

https://github.com/aaroncnb/healpix_coordtrans_example/tree/master

The code there should run very quickly, but that's because the maps are heavily degraded. I did the same for my NSIDE 1024 and 2048 maps, and it took
about an hour.

**------Before and After Images------**

[image: NSIDE 128, Celestial Coordinates: *Before*]

[image: NSIDE 128, Galactic Coordinates: *After*]

Comment: Sorry, I blindly made an example opposite of what was asked:

My example converts Celestial to Galactic coordinates.
Galactic to Celestial was requested.

However, you can easily modify the commands to do Galactic to Celestial.

The ``coord=['C','G']`` keyword in ``cartview`` becomes ``coord=['G','C']``.

The example template header's ``CTYPE`` keywords would be modified to ``RA---CAR`` and ``DEC--CAR``, and the ``COORDSYS`` keyword would become`` 'icrs    '``

Answer (score 1):

This function seems to do the trick (reasonably slow, but should be better than the for loop):

```
def rotate_map(hmap, rot_theta, rot_phi):
    """
    Take hmap (a healpix map array) and return another healpix map array 
    which is ordered such that it has been rotated in (theta, phi) by the 
    amounts given.
    """
    nside = hp.npix2nside(len(hmap))

    # Get theta, phi for non-rotated map
    t,p = hp.pix2ang(nside, np.arange(hp.nside2npix(nside))) #theta, phi

    # Define a rotator
    r = hp.Rotator(deg=False, rot=[rot_phi,rot_theta])

    # Get theta, phi under rotated co-ordinates
    trot, prot = r(t,p)

    # Interpolate map onto these co-ordinates
    rot_map = hp.get_interp_val(hmap, trot, prot)

    return rot_map
```

Using this on data from `PyGSM` gives the following:

`hp.mollview(np.log(rotate_map(gsm.generated_map_data, 0,0)))`

[image]

Upon rotation of `phi`:

`hp.mollview(np.log(rotate_map(gsm.generated_map_data, 0,np.pi)))`

[image]

Or rotating `theta`:

`hp.mollview(np.log(rotate_map(gsm.generated_map_data, np.pi/4,0)))`

[image]