# Healpy: changing coordinates to a map and saving the new one

Tags: python, numpy, coordinate-systems, healpy

I have a map in galactic coordinates and I need to save it in equatorial coordinates in another file .  I know i can use:

```
import healpy as hp
map=hp.read_map('file.fits')
map_rot=hp.mollview(map, coord=['G','C'], return_projected_map=True)
```

and this should return a 2D `numpy` array stored in `map_rot`. But when I read `map_rot`, I found out it is a masked_array filled ONLY with `-inf` values, and `mask=False` , `fill_value=-1.6735e+30`  (so, apparently, `-inf` is not a mask).   Moreover, the total number of elements of `map_rot` do not match with the number of pixels I would expect for a map (`npix=12*nside**2`). For example if `nside=256` I would expect to obtain `npix=786432`, while `map_rot` has `400*800=320000` elements. What's going on?

(I have already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636372/apply-rotation-to-healpix-map-in-healpy), but I have a map in polarization, so I need to rotate Stokes' parameters. Since `mollview` knows how to do that, I was trying to obtain the new map directly from `mollview`. )

Answer (score 0):

One way to go around this is to save the output, for instance with pickle

```
import healpy as hp, pickle
map=hp.read_map('file.fits')
map_rot=hp.mollview(map, coord=['G','C'], return_projected_map=True)
pickle.dump(map_rot, open( "/path/map.p", "wb"))
```

The return value of hp.mollview() has a format that can be displayed using the standard imshow() function. So next time you want to plot it, just do the following

```
map_rot = pickle.load(open("/path/map.p"), 'rb'))
plt.imshow(map_rot)
```

map_rot describes the pixels in the entire matplotlib window, including the white area (-inf color-coded with white) around the ellipsoid.

In contrast, mollview() accepts only an array of pixels which reside in the ellipsoid, i.e. array of the length.

```
 len(hp.pixelfunc.nside2npix(NSIDE))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alex, this partially solves my problem. I need the new map in .fits format too.

Comment: Have you tried astropy? Check out the section "Creating a FITS file from scratch" here: https://python4astronomers.github.io/astropy/fits.html . Turning map_rot into a .fits file should be doable in a few lines (with a header of your choice).