# Rotating a healpy(or healpix) map to an arbitrary direction

Tags: healpy

I have a healpy map that contains an object centered at the location Dec=0 deg and RA=0 deg. Now I want to move the position of the object to an arbitrary point, for instance, Dec=20 deg, RA=10 deg. Is there a simple and precise way of doing the rotation? I red the healpy documentation, but it's still unclear to me how to rotate a map.

Let's say that I have a number array `map` representing a healpy map. Then can you suggest example codes for the rotation?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `rotate_map_alms` method of `hp.Rotator`

```py
longitude = 10 * u.deg
latitude = 20 * u.deg
rot_custom = hp.Rotator(rot=[longitude.to_value(u.deg), latitude.to_value(u.deg)], inv=True)
m_smoothed_rotated_alms = rot_custom.rotate_map_alms(m_smoothed)
```

[image]

I [wrote a full tutorial on how to rotate maps with `healpy`](https://zonca.dev/2021/03/rotate-maps-healpy.html) based on this